# Unrecognized selector sent to instance (SIG_ABRT), adding NSString to NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I'm brainfarting here.  So I have a method that looks through a NSMutableArray that is a property of another class.  The objects are NSString.  In the debugger I see it says NSCFString for the object I'm trying to add to an array.  So I basically do this:

```
- (NSArray *)GetFileNames {
    NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSString *str in self.ParentVC.SelectedOptions) {
        [fileNameArray addObject:str];
        NSLog(@"%@", str); // this works fine
    }
    return fileNameArray;
}
```

And I call this function somewhere else by:

```
    NSArray *fileNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self GetFileNames]];
```

But for some reason, I get the unrecognized selector sent to instance and it stops on this line.  Am I doing something wrong?  Any tips to try to troubleshoot the problem?  I already checked the self.ParentVC.SelectedOptions and that shows my NSCFString or NSCFStrings I want.  Anything I can do in Instruments for this?  Thanks.

Comment: perhaps it should be "NSMutableArray alloc"  ?

Comment: @Alan Moore thanks!  total brainfart!

Comment: You're welcome!  Guess I shoulda put that as an answer :P

Comment: No reputation for Alan Moore. He'll have to settle for being a world famous writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the second line with

```
NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

The real type of the object is what you allocate, not what you declare. In the posted code, the array is not mutable.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Should be

```
NSMutableArray *fileNameArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Otherwise you're creating an immutable array.